# Pagination in custom archive.php page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have created a custom `archive.php` page by adding some extra code to the default `archive.php`. I want to do pagination in that page but I don't know why it is not working.

I use `wp-pagenavi` plugin for pagination. It shows the `page not found` error when I click on the 2nd page. To be more understandable I am posting an image of what is happening.

The image below is what happens when the page loads. You can see the site address which I have marked in red:
[image]

Next is the image of what happens when I click on '2' to navigate to the 2nd page. As you can see the URL is `../?m=201303&paged=2`.

[image]

Below is the code I use for the custom archive page:

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<div class="archive_page">

<?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, 
        array( 'cat' =>'-1,-8,-9',
        'posts_per_page'=>'2',
        'paged' =>$paged));
      query_posts( $args );
     ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

 <header class="page-header">
 <h1 class="page-title">
 <?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
 <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' ); ?>
<?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
<?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'twentyeleven' ) ) . '</span>' ); ?>
    <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
<?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'twentyeleven' ) ) . '</span>' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php _e( 'Blog Archives', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</h1>
    </header>
<div id="navig">
    <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){wp_pagenavi();}?>
</div>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="all_posts">
    <div id="auth_ava">
    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '65');?>
    </div>
    <div class="post_title_archive">
    <?php 
    the_title();
    ?>
    </div>
       <div id="name_date_coment_tag">
           <div id="auth_dis_name">
        <?php the_author_posts_link();?>
       </div>
    <div class="border">|</div>
    <div id="posted_date_archive">
        <?php 
        the_time('F j, Y');
         ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="border">|</div>
    <div class="categories">
        Categories: <?php the_category(', '); ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="border">|</div>
    <div id="tags_archive">
        <?php 
            the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); 
        ?> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="excerpt_archive">
    <?php 
        the_excerpt();
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div id="navig">
       <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){wp_pagenavi();}?>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
        <header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
         <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
    </article>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I am really sorry for a long question. I hope it is clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

***Just try with the following :***

```
<?php
//the query using arguments above
        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        //use the query for paging
        $wp_query->query_vars[ 'paged' ] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars[ 'paged' ] : $current = 1;

        //set the "paginate_links" array to do what we would like it it. Check the codex for examples http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
        $pagination = array(
            'base' => @add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
            //'format' => '',
            'showall' => false,
            'end_size' => 4,
            'mid_size' => 4,
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => $current,
            'type' => 'plain'
        );

        //build the paging links
        if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
            $pagination[ 'base' ] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );

        //more paging links
        if ( !empty( $wp_query->query_vars[ 's' ] ) )
            $pagination[ 'add_args' ] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );

        //run the query
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
```

***Also refer the following locations :***

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32100/pagination-on-a-custom-page-template

And

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-archive-page-pagination-isnt-working

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.